# How to retrieve minimum value(s) from a set of values returned by Sub-query

Tags: sqlite, subquery, min

The following sub-query:

```
SELECT R.mID AS MID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVGSTARS FROM Rating R
GROUP BY R.mID
ORDER BY AVGRSTARS
```

returns the following values:

```
MID   AVGSTARS

104    2.5000
103    2.5000
101    3.0000
108    3.3333
107    4.0000
106    4.5000
```

Now I have to retrieve minimum value(s) from this intermediate result which happens to be

```
MID   AVGSTARS

104    2.5000
103    2.5000
```

For achieving this I have written the following query which ain't working:

```
SELECT INTER1.RMID FROM
(SELECT R.mID AS MID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVGSTARS FROM Rating R
GROUP BY R.mID
ORDER BY AVGRSTARS) INTER1
WHERE MIN(AVGRSTARS) = INTER1.AVRSTARS
```

I know it doesn't work but I would like to write a query on these lines. Can somebody please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide something like [mcve]. E.g. the `.dump` from SQLite command line tool for a suitably tailored toy database. And show some example of desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS ( 
  SELECT R.mID AS MID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVGSTARS 
  FROM Rating R GROUP BY R.mID ) 
SELECT MID, AVGSTARS 
FROM cte 
WHERE AVGSTARS = (SELECT MIN(AVGSTARS) FROM cte);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=dd2aeb51f1543a380562c270276491fc)**

**EDIT:**

MySQL before 8.0:

```
SELECT MID, AVGSTARS 
FROM (SELECT R.mID AS MID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVGSTARS 
      FROM Rating R GROUP BY R.mID ) sub
WHERE AVGSTARS = (SELECT MIN(AVGSTARS) 
                  FROM (SELECT R.mID AS MID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVGSTARS 
                        FROM Rating R GROUP BY R.mID) AS s)
```

Comment: What will be the equivalent MySQL compliant query?

Comment: @dsfasdfadf So it is not SQLite as posted in original question? MariaDB/MySQL 8.0 should work as posted.

Comment: I'm practicing the queries in both MySQL and SQLite. In SQLite it works perfectly well but the problem occurs in MySQL since the version I'm using is v6.3

Comment: @dsfasdfadf Check version without cte

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to write a query with out redundancy of the following query:
SELECT R.mID AS MID, AVG(R.stars) AS AVGSTARS 
FROM Rating R GROUP BY R.mID.

I also had the same thing in mind but then it is not optimal when you have to repeat the same query twice.

Comment: @dsfasdfadf Redundancy is resolved using `CTE`. Unfortunately in old MySQL version it is not supported.